# How to get matrix coordinates from a String in R?

Tags: r, string, matrix

I have a matrix with some small numbers, like this example matrix

```
dataTable = matrix(1:12, nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
```

And I have a list of coordinates for that matrix, like in this example

```
dataList = c("2,1","3,2","1,4")
```

The problem is that since the coordinates are saved as strings, there's no easy way to process this.

The way I'm trying to do this is by using

```
dataTable[as.numeric(substring(dataList[2],1,1)),as.numeric(substring(dataList[2],3,3))]
```

This seems like a huge bodge and also doesn't scale past matrixes sized 10. Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: `dataTable[as.matrix(read.table(text = dataList, sep = ","))]`

Comment: This does it, thank you so much!